# Princeton wordnet prolog files - how to use sense key

Tags: prolog, nlp, wordnet

I have downloaded the priceton wordnet prolog database file and creting a wordnet application of my own. i figured out almost all other except how to use the sensekey (wn_sk.pl), grouped verbs (wn_vgp.pl), syntax and verb frames!!

so far, my app can get synonyms, antonyms, hypernym, hyponym, gloss, attributes, cause, etc,.,

help me!!

Comment: Do you want to use nltk or prolog?

Comment: @QuentinPradet: OP clearly references Prolog files. But the language is actually not very relevant, compared to the complexity of the database.

Comment: do you know the [ProNTo](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/ProNTo/) tools, specifically Witzig [documentation](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/ProNTo/Witzig.pdf) ?

Comment: I want to use prolog files...

Comment: the OP question has nothing to do with the NLTK, i've removed the NLTK tag. To use the WN interface in NLTK, see http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html

Answer (score 1):

The sk facts point back to so called lexicographer files. These
files are not part of the WordNet database package. But the
WordNet database package is generated from these files.

The encoding of these backward pointers is documented here:

```
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/senseidx.5WN.html  
(See section Sense Key Encoding)
```

The lexicographer files itself are documented here:

```
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/lexnames.5WN.html  
(See section Lexicographer Files)
```

So probably you can extract from the sk facts some toplevel
categories of the words. Like whether a verb is a verb
of emotion or a verb of communication. Etc..

Just a guess.

Bye